# WCF Data Service produces 'Ambiguous Match Found' error when adding service reference

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I have an application that is using POCO classes generated by the DBcontext generator tool. After creating these POCO classes I copy the Model.tt file to a different namespace in another project in my solution. I correct the refence in the Model.tt file to point to the edmx file.  I create a WCF Data Service pointing at the DBcontext.  I also add a using statement in the Model.Context.cs file so that the context uses the moved POCO classes. When I try to read the meta data for the WCF Data Service I get the following error:

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Ambiguous match found.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:

at System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers) at System.Type.GetProperty(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr) at System.Data.Services.Providers.ObjectContextServiceProvider.PopulateMemberMetadata(ResourceType resourceType, IProviderMetadata workspace, IDictionary`2 knownTypes, PrimitiveResourceTypeMap primitiveResourceTypeMap) at System.Data.Services.Providers.ObjectContextServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata(IDictionary`2 knownTypes, IDictionary`2 childTypes, IDictionary`2 entitySets) at System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.PopulateMetadata() at System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.LoadMetadata() at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateMetadataAndQueryProviders(IDataServiceMetadataProvider& metadataProviderInstance, IDataServiceQueryProvider& queryProviderInstance, BaseServiceProvider& builtInProvider, Object& dataSourceInstance) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider() at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest() at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream messageBody) at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

If I leave the POCO classes in the project that contains the edmx, the WCF data Service works fine.  I can retrieve metadata, create a service reference and use the service.

What could be causing the 'Ambiguous match found.' error message?  How can I access the server log and analyze the information?

Comment: because of copying - don't you end with two sets of classes in different namespaces?

Comment: After copying to the Business project, I delete the Model.tt and it's classess from the data framework project.